# In which category is the supercomputer SUMMIT according to Flynn's taxonomy?

Tags: computer-architecture

I have read that the POWER9 processor is an SIMD processor.
I have also read that most supercomputers are MIMD based.

So is the SUMMIT supercomputer SIMD? And if it is can you name a supercomputer that is MIMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summit is a parallel system that [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summit_(supercomputer)) contains many nodes, where each node is powered by one or more [POWER9 processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POWER9).  Each POWER9 processor contains a vector scalar unit that Wikipedia says can be described as a SIMD unit.  However, the Summit system as a whole would normally be used in a [MIMD mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMD), as each POWER9 processor can run a separate program. It doesn't have to -- you could run the same code on each node, or different code on each node -- but each node runs asynchronously and independently, so I would classify the entire system as MIMD.